# MongoDB Keep path where a criteria is met

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB.

In the find query I'm using the following structure:

```
db.report.find({'accountList.transactionList.description': /.*aear.*/i})
```

However, accountList contains multiple values, and so does transaction list, the exact query would be:

```
db.report.find({'accountList[0].transactionList[4].description': /.*aear.*/i})
```

The problem is that accountList has multiple accounts, and only one of them has the value 'aear' in the description. When I'm executing the query it returns me both accounts, and I'd like to keep only the account where aear is in its description. Also, this MUST be iterable over many files, since it file has different transactionLists, therefore in some documents ***aear*** will not appear at all, and in others it might appear multiple types, always in different positions. I believe something must be done in projection, but setting it like this doesn't work:

```
.projection({"accountList.id":1,"accountList.transactionList.description":1})
```

Here's the output:

```
"accountList" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : [
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-25T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                },
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-25T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
                    "description" : "bb"
                },
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-25T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
                    "description" : "cc"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "USD",
            "transactionList" : [
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-15T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
                    "description" : "aa",
                },
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-14T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
                    "description" : "ee"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

And I'd like something like this, where I''m only getting the path to where the condition is met:

```
"accountList" : [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : [
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-25T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                },
```

Comment: Hi! Are you sure about the JSON being returned on your query? It has duplicate data. You shouldn't have two `id` and `transactionList` inside the same document: `{
      "id": "4474",
      "transactionList": [{"description": "aear"},{"description": "koe"}],
      "id": "4475",
      "transactionList": [{"description": "oho"},{"description": "koe"}]
}`. Could you post the actual structure for a document inside the collection `report`, please?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my answer

Comment: There, I finished the edit.

Comment: Thanks. Check my answer if you didn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that you need to use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). I believe this code will work in your case:

```
db.report.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "accountList.transactionList.description": { $regex: "aear", $options: "i"} } },
  { "$unwind": "$accountList" },
  { "$unwind": "$accountList.transactionList" },
  { "$match": { "accountList.transactionList.description": { $regex: "aear", $options: "i"} } },
  { "$group": {
      "_id": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "accountListId": "$accountList.id",
          "accountListType": "$accountList.type",
          "accountListCurrency": "$accountList.currency",
      },
      "transactionList": { "$push": "$accountList.transactionList" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "accountList": {
          "$push": {
              "id": "$_id.accountListId",
              "type": "$_id.accountListType",
              "currency": "$_id.accountListCurrency",
              "transactionList": "$transactionList"
          }
      }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try this answer giving the fact aear can be present in many forms and should be used as a regex (aEar, aeAR, AEAR, laearl, etc..)

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot I just editted the regex part to: { $regex: /.*aear.*/i}

Answer (score 1):

Updating my answer as this question got updated with new required o/p :

**Answer for New Question :**

If you've only one transaction matching to given criteria `/.*aear.*/i`, let's say description is unique across **accountList** array of report document(exact for provided sample):

```
db.report.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            'accountList.transactionList.description': /.*aear.*/i
        }
    },{ $unwind: '$accountList' },{ $unwind: '$accountList.transactionList' },{$match :{ 'accountList.transactionList.description': /.*aear.*/i}}, { $project: { 'accountList': 1, _id: 0 } }])
```

But, if you've multiple descriptions (across multiple objects in accountsList array of a report document) matches to given criteria in accountList :

```
db.report.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        'accountList.transactionList.description': /.*aear.*/i
    }
}, { $unwind: '$accountList' }, { $unwind: '$accountList.transactionList' }, { $match: { 'accountList.transactionList.description': /.*aear.*/i } },
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', accountList: { $push: '$accountList' }, data: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }
    , { $addFields: { 'data.accountList': '$accountList' } }, { $replaceRoot: { 'newRoot': '$data' } }, { $project: { 'accountList': 1, _id: 0 } }
])
```

**Output :**

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1100",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : {
                "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "description" : "aear"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1200",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "USD",
            "transactionList" : {
                "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "description" : "aear"
            }
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : {
                "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "description" : "aear"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If in case you've multiple matching descriptions in transaction array & also in other objects of accounts array (this will work for all above scenarios as well but it might not be needed as per requirement, it can be bulky, Check document#3 in Output for clarification) :

```
db.report.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "accountList.transactionList.description": /.*aear.*/i } },
    { "$unwind": "$accountList" },
    { "$unwind": "$accountList.transactionList" },
    { "$match": { "accountList.transactionList.description": /.*aear.*/i } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "docId": "$_id",
                "accountsListObjId": "$accountList.id"
            },
            "transactionList": { "$push": "$accountList.transactionList" },
            "accountList": { "$first": '$accountList' }
        }
    }
    , { $addFields: { 'accountList.transactionList': '$transactionList' } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.docId",
            "accountList": { $push: '$accountList' }
        }
    }, { $project: { 'accountList': 1, _id: 0 } }
])
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1100",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1200",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "USD",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "00",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "EUR",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "100",
            "type" : "xD",
            "currency" : "USD",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "onDate" : ISODate("2019-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    "description" : "aear"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you're looking for exact text, you can do this as well(cause regex is not allowed in cond) :

```
db.report.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'accountList.transactionList.description': 'aear'
        }
    }, { $unwind: '$accountList' }, {
        $addFields: {
            'accountList.transactionList': {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$accountList.transactionList',
                    as: 'eachTransaction',
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$eachTransaction.description", 'aear'] }
                }
            }
        }
    }, { $match: { 'accountList.transactionList': { $ne: [] } } }, { $group: { _id: '$_id', accountList: { $push: '$accountList' }, data: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }
    , { $addFields: { 'data.accountList': '$accountList' } }, { $replaceRoot: { 'newRoot': '$data' } }, { $project: { 'accountList': 1, _id: 0 } }])
```

**Output :** Same as above.

**Answer for Old Question :**

Ok you've two options here, Please try these :

If you've only one object in `accountList` which does matches with the given filter then you can simply do this:

```
db.report.find({'accountList.transactionList.description': /.*aear.*/i}, {'accountList.$': 1})
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df0c7"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "4474",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df0d7"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "4400",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df077"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "0000",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df1c7"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "0101",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Downside of above `.find ()` query is it would get only first matching object in `accountList`, If you've multiple matching objects for given filter in `accountList` then you need to use **aggregation** (this aggregation query can be used for earlier scenario as well, Please check output for diff) :

```
db.report.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                "accountList.transactionList.description": /.*aear.*/i
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$accountList" },
        {
            $match: {
                "accountList.transactionList.description": /.*aear.*/i
            }
        }, { $group: { _id: '$_id', accountList: { $push: '$accountList' }, doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $addFields: { 'doc.accountList': '$accountList' } },
        { $replaceRoot: { 'newRoot': '$doc' } }
    ])
```

**Output :**

```
// This first object is best example where you need aggregation

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df1c7"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "0101",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1111",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df0d7"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "4400",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df077"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "0000",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6435145a0d22d3c86df0c7"),
    "accountList" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "4474",
            "transactionList" : [ 
                {
                    "description" : "aear"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "koe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it tomorrow!

Comment: @CeliusStingher : Does these work for you? Or still any issue?

Comment: This might be a little silly, but I'm totally new to MongoDB, I'm getting this message " "message" : "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." However I got this after trying it for a second time, the first time I managed to get the results however I got the full output, not the 'filtered' one.

Comment: @CeliusStingher : which query did you use ? is your $match working as expected ? And how large is your dataset after $match applied ?

Comment: I've used the second code you propose in your answer. I'm sorry I've been asking long to reply. I've been assigned into somethign drastically different and my attention is there now. I'm upvoting it given the explination and effort put into it, plus it's probably correct and I'm having trouble implementing it.

Comment: @CeliusStingher : not a problem, Does your all documents look similar to what is given in question ? Where 'aear' is present only once though accountList has multiple documents & also transactionList inside accountList has multiple documents ? Or do you think 'aear' gets repeated again and again inside one document? If that's the case you can use query 1..

Comment: It does repeat multiple times, because each account (at most 4 or 5) has a lot of items in its transaction list (some 10, others over 500) and these transactions might have 'aear' somewhere in their description, if they do, it can be any number of times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198678/discussion-between-srinivasy-and-celius-stingher).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
db.report.find({'accountList[0].transactionList[4].description': { $regex: /.*aear.*/i} })
```

OR - Which will return only the first matching document:

```
db.report.find({'accountList[0].transactionList[4].description': /.*aear.*/i}).limit(1)
```

Comment: I doubt this work since to make it iterable over many files it shouldn't contain the exact position `[0]` and `[4]`. Thanks for your answer